# Is createElement() supported in html5?

Tags: javascript, css, html, browser, doctype

While coding an HTML5 Page (PHP included) I noticed that createElement() stops working when the doctype is switched to html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The code is pretty standard element creation with Javascript:

```
function Rhit(){
        var Hit=document.createElement('div');
        if(Hit){
            alert('Hit assigned.');
            Hit.setAttribute('id','Hits');
            if(document.body.appendChild(Hit)){
                alert('Hit transferred to body; setting styles.');
                Hit.style.width='400';
                Hit.style.height='400';
                Hit.style.position='absolute';
                Hit.style.right='0';
                Hit.style.top='0';
                Hit.style.backgroundColor='#777777';
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('Create Element Error, please debug.');
        }

    }
```

(I've debugged it a bit under the html5 doc type... sort of.)
The alerts pop up, but no div tags are drawn under the html5 doctype. (Works fine with regular html super sandbox mode)

Am I missing something?

(Also, all code shows up in browser source.) It seems like the code is being parsed but not drawn?

EDIT: Here's a full demo. In the meantime I'm added those comments in:

```
<html> <!--if !html5 document draws.-->
<head> 
 <script>
     function proc(){
        var foo=document.createElement('div');

        //Test foo creation.
        if(foo){
            alert('Hit assigned.'); 
            foo.setAttribute('id','Hits');

            //test foo location assignment.
            if(document.body.appendChild(foo)){

                alert('Hit transferred to body; setting styles.'); 

                //Set all other stuff.
                foo.style.width='400';
                foo.style.height='400';
                foo.style.position='absolute';
                foo.style.right='0';
                foo.style.top='0';
                foo.style.backgroundColor='#777777';
            }
        }
        //If failed, all is lost.
        else{
            alert('Create Element Error, please debug.');
        }

    }
 </script>
</head>
<title></title>
<body>
    <script>
    proc(); //Run function.
    document.write('Javascript Running...');
    //Failsafe (for IDE's who don't care if your eyes hurt and insist
    //that java has an error "somewhere".)
    </script>   
</body>
```

Comment: `id` is a property, not an attribute, so `Hit.id = 'Hits';`

Comment: HTML5 most definitely supports `createElement()`.  Must be something else wrong with your test.

Comment: @Jack in the HTML side of life it is an attribute mapped to a element property

Comment: Could you create a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: your style definitions are wrong. you need to specify percent or pixels for height/width

Comment: @rlemon Yeah, but that doesn't mean you should use `setAttribute()` to set it.

Comment: @Jack nope, that is also looking hairy, but it is not technically incorrect. It should still work regardless of using setAttribute or .id

Comment: I pasted your code into JSFiddle, fixed the 400px issue, and it worked fine. JSFiddle uses the html5 `<doctype html>` by default.

Comment: Thanks again guys! On a side note, `foo.id` looks prettier. Some code is force of habit. Awesome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your height and width are defined incorrectly and are therefore (iirc) being assigned `0`.

These CSS style rules require values be percent or pixels. So:

```
Hit.style.width = '400px';
Hit.style.height = '400px';
```

should give the element some dimensions, and let it be seen.